# SWIG2 with NUMPY

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig

I am trying to build a SWIG2.0 interface for my C++ class. Only requirement is that I need to be able to pass a numpy array from python into the C++ class.

I have a simple C++ Class as :

```
//
// File : matmanip.h
//
#ifndef __MAT_MANIP_H
#define __MAT_MANIP_H

#include <iostream>


class MatManip
{
public:
  MatManip();

  // Matrix of length d
  void set_matrix( float * M, int d );

};

#endif
```

The .cpp file :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "matmanip.h"

// File : matmanip.cpp
MatManip::MatManip() { std::cout << "Constructor\n"; }

void MatManip::set_matrix( float * M, int d )
{
  for( int i=0 ; i<d ; i++ )
    std::cout << "M[" << i << "] = " << M[i] << std::endl;
}
```

My swig interface file (matmanip.i). I obtained numpy.i file from https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/tools/swig/numpy.i :

```
%module matmanip

%{
#define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
#include "matmanip.h"
%}

%include "numpy.i"

%init %{
import_array();
%}


%apply( float * IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double * seq, int n) };
%include "matmanip.h"
```

Here is what I do to compile:

```
    $ swig -c++ -python matmanip.i
    $ g++ -fPIC -c matmanip.cpp
    $ g++ -fPIC -c matmanip_wrap.cxx -I /usr/include/python2.7
    $ g++ -shared matmanip.o matmanip_wrap.o  -o _matmanip.so
    $ ls
matmanip.cpp  matmanip.o    _matmanip.so       numpy.i
matmanip.h    matmanip.py   matmanip_wrap.cxx
matmanip.i    matmanip.pyc  matmanip_wrap.o
```

Until this point everything work! I can even see the _matmanip.so.

However, as I try to import matmanip in python here is the error

```
$ python
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from matmanip import MatManip
>>> m = MatManip()
Constructor
>>> m.set_matrix( np.array( [2.0, 3.4, 5.8] ) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "matmanip.py", line 82, in set_matrix
    def set_matrix(self, *args): return _matmanip.MatManip_set_matrix(self, *args)
TypeError: MatManip_set_matrix() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
>>>
```

I am really puzzled! My swig version is 2.0.12. Numpy is 1.12.1. Python version is 2.7.12. g++ version is 5.4.0. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This is a completely different error than before editing... You passed one argument to `set_matrix` but it expects two (`M` and `d`).  (the third argument is the class instance, which is passed automatically.)

Comment: Yes it is different error. I had forgotten to define the constructor before, which I fixed. ! But can't fix this new error. Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Well... I suggest you pass one more argument to the function?! For example `m.set_matrix(np.array([2.0, 3.4, 5.8]), 3)`.

Comment: m.set_matrix( np.array([2.0, 3.4, 5.8]) , 3 ) gives the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "matmanip.py", line 82, in set_matrix
    def set_matrix(self, *args): return _matmanip.MatManip_set_matrix(self, *args)
TypeError: in method 'MatManip_set_matrix', argument 2 of type 'float *'

Comment: Numpy's default data type is `double` (although they call it float in Python). You may be able to fix this error by changing your function to take a `double *` instead of a `float *` or you can try to create the array with `np.array([2.0, 3.4, 5.8], dtype=np.float32)`. Not sure if this will help, though.

Comment: That does not help!

Comment: Sorry about that. Good luck!

Comment: replace `%apply( float * IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(double * seq, int n) };` with `%apply( float * IN_ARRAY1, int DIM1) {(float* M, int d) };` and you should be good to go. You need to allocate your array as floats using NumPy, e.g. `arr = np.ones(45, dtype=np.float32)`